# how to send a command to a jupyter terminal over a Http request?

Tags: python, http, jupyter-notebook

I have opened a jupyter terminal at `http://localhost:8888/terminals/1` is there a way to send a POST request to this url in order to run a command. for example `{"command":"ls"}` to see what files are there or `{"command":"python runsomething.py"}`.

**EDIT**

i know how to run **general** terminal commands (**not** jupyter notebook terminal)from a notebook cell using `!python runsomething.py etc`. What i am interested is purely an http communication with a terminal opened from jupyter.

**UPDATE!!**

the strangest thing just happened. i typed in my browser URL `http://localhost:8888/terminals/10` pressed enter and a new terminal was created! I assume it was a GET request. We are close... I can make one now. help me send a command to it.

Comment: For what I can see, you are sending `ls` `python runsomething.py` to shell， not jupyter terminal.

Comment: sorry. i clarified my edit